# Surjectivity of the reduction map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a local field $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. It's obvious that we can choose a model such that $E$ is defined over the ring of integer $\mathcal{O}_{K_{\frak{p}}}$. Thus, we may define the reduction map $\pi_{\frak{p}}$ from $E(K_{\frak{p}})$ to $E(k)$, where $k$ is the residue field w.r.t $\frak{p}$. Note that $E(k)$ may be a singular curve.

Is $\pi_{\frak{p}}$ always surjective? If not, can we get some concrete examples?

Comment: I feel like this should be surjective. If you have some model of your elliptic curve over your residue field, take some lift of the coefficients to $\mathcal{O}_{K_p}$. If $(a,b)$ in the lift is not smooth, that means the partials at $[x_0:y_0:z_0]$ are zero. By working with projective coordinates, we may assume that $[x_0,y_0,z_0]\in \mathcal{O}_{K_p}$. If we reduce this to the residue field, $k$, we get that evaluating the partial at $[\bar{x_0}:\bar{y_0}:\bar{z_0}]$ is zero. Note that this is indeed a point on $E(k)$ and so that is a singular point of $E(k)$ which would be bad.

Comment: @daruma Thanks! I almost agree with your point. It seems that if $E(k)$ is non-singular, then I believe $\pi_{\frak{p}}$ is surjective (like you said probably Hensel's lemma?). But, is there any chance that $\pi_{\frak{p}}$ may NOT map the singularity of $E(k)$? That'll give an example...right?

Comment: As we are dealing with local fields, I think there should be a inclution $k \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{K_{\mathfrak{p}}}$. So, lifting always can be done.

Comment: @Offlaw: this would work for function fields, but not $p$-adic fields.

Comment: @Mindlack: I'm just thinking like $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ as $m \mapsto (m, m, \dots)$.

Comment: @Offlaw, you're claiming there is an injection of characteristic $p$ ring into a characteristic $0$ one.....

Comment: When the mod $p$ reduction is smooth, a hensels lemma argument will work (fix a $y$-coordinate which lifts). In general the fact to look up is that $E_0(K) \to \tilde{E}_{ns}$ (the nonsingular reduction) is always surjective. Now the index $[E(K):E_0(K)]$ is the tamagawa number (is finite by Kodaira and Neron)

Comment: contd... However a curve with bad reduction can still have tamagawa number $1$, consider the elliptic curve with Cremona label $11a2$, this has minimal discriminant $-11$, and split multiplicative reduction, hence tamagawa number $v(\Delta(E)) = 1$ - in particular the sinuglar point cannot be hit.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey: Thanks! This map cannot be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: For Q, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113968/surjectivity-of-reduction-maps-of-elliptic-curves-over-q. For local fields, surjectivity over the _non-singular points_ is proposition VII.2.1 in Silverman. For singular points, take $E : y^2 = x^3 + p$, and $(0,0) \in \tilde E$. It does not lift to $E(\Bbb Q_p)$.